# Selecting node using Nokogiri and then the next specified node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to select two nodes together in an XML document and print them out.
I can't seem to get them to print together. They are always output as 'list of first nodes' then 'list of second nodes'. An example would illustrate better:

```
<result>
   <name>Peter</name>
   <school>main school</school>
   ...
   <score>4.5</score>
</result>
<result>
   <name>John</name>
   ..
   ...
   <score>3.5</score>
</result>
```

The formats of each `<result>` are not always the same. I need to select `<name>` and `<score>` so they appear together:

```
Peter
4.5
John
3.5
```

or

```
Peter   4.5
John    3.5
```

I can only get the results so far like this:

```
Peter
John
4.5
3.5
```

I've been trying various different methods like:

```
doc.xpath("//name/").xpath("//score").each do |link|
  puts link
```

and other combinations of nested `do`/`end` loops, but nothing works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your XML isn't valid. It's important to provide usable content that we can use with the code you supply. Your code doesn't do anything as it's not syntactically correct. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest way would probably to first select the `result` nodes, then for each `result` select its `name` and `score` nodes:

```
doc.xpath('//result').each do |result|
  name = result.at_xpath('./name').text
  score = result.at_xpath('./score').text
  # handle name and score however you want...
end
```

(This assumes each `result` has a single `name` child and a single `score` child.)

Comment: Thank you. This is a concise answer to the problem. I didn't realise I could format the selections like './name' , etc. Works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could store the `name` values in an array, and then iterate over the array as you iterate over the `score` values, printing them both at the same time:

```
array_of_names = []

doc.xpath("//name").each do |name|
  array_of_names << name
end

counter = 0
doc.xpath("//score").each do |score|
  puts "#{array_of_names[counter]}: #{score}"
  counter += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks @GDP2. I selected the other answer below as it's more compact but I see your solution would also work. I appreciate the work.

Comment: @boogiewonder Np, I also agree that the other answer is valid. There is more than one way to do it, as they say. Thanks for the upvote, btw.